# how to reset or delete request params in EcomDev_PHPUnit?

Tags: magento-1.9, ecomdev-phpunit

How to completely reset a request params between dispatches ?

In Ecomdev_Phpunit I did an upload test, set request like this:

`$this->getRequest()->setParam('upload', "");`

and params becomes:

```
    $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    array (
      'upload' => '',
    )
```

Then I want to make another test, but i need that `upload` empty param to be deleted.

How to I get rid of these parameter in scope of single test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with

`$this->getRequest()->resetParams();`

In case of the base **EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case**, this is not possible. Alternatively, the default request is available via `Mage::app()->getRequest()` then.

Comment: How does it will work in Magento 2 ?